# how can i programatically open a docx file, edit it, and then seal it up again without it breaking?

Tags: php, converters, openoffice.org, docx, libreoffice

I have a web application that converts microsoft word documents to html using LibreOffice. Everything has been working great, but I am having some issues with their ability to interpret indentation on certain files.

Using suggestions from other kind developers, I have discovered how to pull apart the docx file by converting it to a zip, unzipping it, and then extracting the document.xml file. in the process, I have noticed that LibreOffice is consistently incapable of interpreting any `<w:tab>` tags and rendering them as indentations.

I have tried many things to fix this, but I am running out of ideas. My last ditch effort was going to be to use php to programatically replace all of the `<w:tab>` tags with `<w:ind>` tags (which LibreOffice successfully interprets as tabs). However, as soon as i convert the file to .zip with bash I am unable to seal it back up as a docx. I mean, i can do it, but LibreOffice no longer recognizes it and throws a strange error at me.

Is there any way I can get an html rendering from just pulling the document.xml file? If not, does anybody know how to seal these documents back up again? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Here is an update: it seems that when i try to zip the docx back up it is including the parent directory. I think this is messing up the file when i convert it back to docx format. I cant seem to figure out how to zip up all of the contents of a folder without zipping up the folder as well. any ideas? Here is the code so far:

```
cp mydoc.docx mydoc.zip
unzip -d mydoc mydoc.zip
zip -r my_edited_doc mydoc/*
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer! To accomplish modifications and rezip the file, make sure you are not including the parent directory of the zipped files. to do this, i changed directories into the parent directory and then ran the following code:

```
zip -r mydoc ./*
```

the full code looks like this:

```
cp mydoc.docx mydoc.zip
unzip -d mydoc mydoc.zip
cd mydoc
zip -r mydoc_converted ./*
```